# How to find how Amazon AMI created date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to find out Amazon EC2 AMI creation date/time from AWS Console or command line?

Note: I am not looking for instance creation, rather when was a particular AMI created?

Answer (score 7):

Querying the creation date of an AMI has been a requested feature since 2006.

Back when I was creating community AMIs in 2007-2009 I started a trend of including the creation date in the AMI name/description (e.g., 20121210).  This practice has been picked up by a number of popular AMI series, so you may want to check out the name and description of the AMI for a date looking string.

Answer (score 7):

[From AWS's 'What's New' :](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/04/search-and-sort-your-amazon-machine-images-ami-by-creation-date/)

> AMI Creation Date is now available on the AWS Management Console. You can find this attribute by going to the EC2 console and choosing AMIs on the left navigation menu. You should see a new column on the AMIs page called "Creation Date"

You can also see this 'CreationDate' attribute with AWS EC2 CLI using:

```
ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-a3e0thy0
```

Answer (score 5):

Two alternatives:

1) You can view info about the associated snapshot from the EC2 snapshot panel, specifically the "Started" field which will tell you the time the snapshot started. I think this is very close, and worked well for AMIs my coworkers and I created - not so well for private AMIs. Simply find the snapshot ID (snapshot-1234abcd) in the AMI view in the "Block devices" field, then look up that snapshot in the Snapshots view.

2) If you are in a region which offers AWS CloudTrail, you can probably find that info in the CloudTrail logs.

Comment: yep, it seems snapshot is the way to go. See also http://serverfault.com/a/577224/70242

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently possible.  The ability to better track versions of AMIs is a often requested feature though.  Expect AWS to be releasing some enhancements in this area relatively soon.

Comment: If two and a half years later counts as "soon", your prediction was correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the CLI, but only want the image ID and the creation date, you can run this:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-XXXXXXXX --query 'Images[*].[ImageId,CreationDate]'
```